# Using rm with extended globbing in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, rm

I need to do daily cleanup of a folder for my app, so I ve made a bash script (with some help of superuser) to do so.

It work well from the console, but it is not interpreted correctly from node.

Here the working script:

```
rm ./app/download/!("test1"|"test4");
```

Which I ve thought would work like this in node.js:

```
 var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
     PATH = process.argv[1].substr(0, process.argv[1].lastIndexOf('/') + 1), //Get the full path to the directory of the app
     arg = [PATH + 'download/!(\"', 'test1', '\"|\"', 'test4', ('\")'],
     child = spawn ('rm', arg);

 child.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
      console.log('stderr:' + data);
 });
```

But I get rm interpret them by being different files:

```
 stderr:rm: cannot remove '/home/user/app/download("' : No such file or directory
 rm cannot remove 'test1' : No such file or directory
 ...
```

So I ve tried by changing arg to this:

```
 arg = [PATH + 'download/!("' + 'test1' + '"|"' + 'test4' + '")']
```

But I get

```
 stderr:rm: cannot remove '/home/user/app/download/!("test1"|"test2")' : No such file or directory
```

I m trying with exec, but I don t think this is the problem since it seems the spawned rm don t interpret the extended glob thing, which is active by default...

EDIT: As a workaround, I m trying to do a sh script which would start this command with as many parameter I start it with for the file to keep. It s not as I wanted it, but for now I just need something which would work.

Comment: The shell doesn't interpret the literal form probably. Moreover some bash instances don't have extended patterns by default so you have to call it with it. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your lines to:

```
 arg = ['-c', "shopt -s extglob\nshopt -s nullglob\nrm " + PATH + 'download/!("test1"|"test4")'],
 child = spawn ('bash', arg);
```

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I was trying around with exec (unsuccessfully). With this I get bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unex^pected token '(' bash: -c: line 0: 'shopt -s extglob; rm /home/user/app/download/!("test1"|"test4")'. But it still a step ahead since it start the bash.

Comment: @DrakaSAN I found the problem. It seems like extglob would be activated on the next line, not on the current line where commands are just separated by semicolons. So we use a newline to separate the commands instead. I it hope it works for you now. Please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark when it does, thanks.

Comment: Tried it, I get rm: cannot remove '/home/user/app/download/!(test1|test4)': No such file or directory. The strange thing is even with \" it don t keep the " in the line.

Comment: @DrakaSAN Please see update. At least we could test if extglob really works.

Comment: Don t worry, I m writing the script while continuing to testing, it would be perfect if I could avoid having external script to call. I ve tested the update, I get rm: missing operand

Comment: @DrakaSAN It seems like extglob works and /home/user/app/download/!(test1|test4) actually doesn't match anything. Can you check if the files really exist?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37642/discussion-between-drakasan-and-konsolebox)